# Php codes are shown in source codes

Tags: php, nginx

I have just moved to nginx and updated my php to php5.3. Now all my PHP code is displaying in the page source code like this:

```
 <div class="bar-icon">
        <!-- FaceBook Share -->  
                 <?php include ('facebook_icon_like.php')?> 
        <!-- /FaceBook Share --> 
  </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: What OS? It sounds like PHP wasn't set up properly if it's being displayed in the source.

Comment: @wanovak Ubuntu Linux 10.04.3

Comment: Does your PHP code executes at all?

Comment: No PHP code does not executes

Comment: +1 to offset anonymous downvote. Don't downvote for poor English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that your nginx engine doesn't have PHP enabled. Follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable PHP into your Nginx server.
If you are using PHP-FPM you could add something like this to your configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    root   /var/www/default/public;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, if the file extension is not `.php`, and you haven't specified any rules for nginx to parse PHP on non-`.php` files as PHP files, then those files will not execute PHP code.

Change the extension to `.php`

Comment: sorry i put wrong comment ..... it should have this 'No PHP code does not executes' .... so confused (